# net.IP does not implement net.Addr (missing Network method)

Tags: go

I have the following code. I'm getting this error:

testdl.go:17: cannot use q (type net.IP) as type net.Addr in field value:
    net.IP does not implement net.Addr (missing Network method)

Any idea how to put a hardcoded IP into LocalAddr?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

var url = "http://URL/api.xml"

func main() {

    q := net.ParseIP("192.168.0.1")

    var transport = &http.Transport{
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            LocalAddr: q,
        }).Dial,
    }
    var httpclient = &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }

    response, err := httpclient.Get(url)
    fmt.Println(response)
}
```

Comment: You should now use `DialContext`. See the definition for DefaultTransport in the [`http` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) for an example.

Comment: Getting the same error when using DialContext as with @T.Claverie's answer: 

Error: dial tcp: mismatched local address type 192.168.0.1

Comment: That's has nothing to do with using the DialContext or not. I'm just informing you that Dial is deprecated and you should prefer DialContext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, indeed the `IP` type does not implement `Addr`. However, the type `IPAddr` does:

```
type IPAddr struct {
    IP   IP
    Zone string // IPv6 scoped addressing zone
}
```

Therefore, your code becomes:

```
q := net.ParseIP("192.168.0.1")
addr := &net.IPAddr{q,""}

var transport = &http.Transport{
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{
        LocalAddr: addr,
    }).Dial,
}
```

Comment: Thanks that produces no error. Only somehow the http.Get never reaches the server defined in var url. When checking http logs I see no requests and  fmt.Println(response) procudes: <nil>

Error: dial tcp: mismatched local address type 192.168.0.1

Comment: This issue is unrelated to this thread, maybe you should post another question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Docs, Luke...

https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveIPAddr

If you use the IPAddr struct, that should solve your problem.